# How to extract integer after "=" sign using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to extract the integers after `mrp=` and `talktime=`.

```
var i=0;
var recharge=[];
var recharge_text=[];
var recharge_String="";
var mrp="";
var talktime="";
var validity="";
var mode="";mrp='1100';
talktime='1200.00';
validity='NA';
mode='E-Recharge';
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
 String.prototype.trim = function() {
 return this.replace(/^ +| +$/g, '');
 }
}
mrp=mrp.trim();
if(isNaN(mrp))
{
recharge_text.push({MRP:mrp, Talktime:talktime, Validity:validity ,Mode:mode});
}
else
{
mrp=parseInt(mrp);
recharge.push({MRP:mrp, Talktime:talktime, Validity:validity ,Mode:mode});
}
mrp='2200';
talktime='2400.00';
```

I've extracted the above text from a webpage, but I do not know how to extract that particular part alone.

Comment: hari, could you explain what you mean by *extract* and what the purpose of doing that is? I just reformatted the code you supplied, but I'm getting the feeling now that you're scraping info, so it'd be good if you clarified.

Comment: use `.to_i` to get int from string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect to see your attempt at solving the problem. Stack Overflow isn't a "give me code" site, instead it's a "we help you debug your code" site. Please add the minimal example of the code you've written toward solving this and we'll be happy to help. Also, your question isn't well defined. The values you want occur multiple times in the captured text. *Which* occurrences do you want? The first, the last, all of them? Please edit your question and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
string = <<EOT
var i=0;
var recharge=[];
var recharge_text=[];
var recharge_String="";
var mrp="";
var talktime="";
var validity="";
var mode="";mrp='1100';
talktime='1200.00';
validity='NA';
mode='E-Recharge';
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
String.prototype.trim = function() {
return this.replace(/^ +| +$/g, '');
}
}
mrp=mrp.trim();
if(isNaN(mrp))
{
recharge_text.push({MRP:mrp, Talktime:talktime, Validity:validity ,Mode:mode});
}
else
{
mrp=parseInt(mrp);
recharge.push({MRP:mrp, Talktime:talktime, Validity:validity ,Mode:mode});
}
mrp='2200';
talktime='2400.00';
EOT

hits = string.scan(/(?:mrp|talktime)='[\d.]+'/)
# => ["mrp='1100'", "talktime='1200.00'", "mrp='2200'", "talktime='2400.00'"]
```

This gives us an array of hits using [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-scan), where the pattern `/(?:mrp|talktime)='[\d.]+'/` matched in the string. Figuring out how the pattern works is left as an exercise for the user, but Ruby's [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html) documentation explains it all.

Cleaning that up to be a bit more useful:

```
hash = hits.map{ |s|
  str, val = s.split('=')
  [str, val.delete("'")]
}.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }){ |(str, val), h| h[str] << val }
```

You also need to read about [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and what's happening with [`Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) as those are important concepts to learn in Ruby.

At this point, `hash` is a hash of arrays:

```
hash # => {"mrp"=>["1100", "2200"], "talktime"=>["1200.00", "2400.00"]}
```

You can easily extract a particular variable's values, and can correlate them if need be.

---

> what if i get a string instead of integer next to "=" sign?
>
> ...
>
> `string.scan(/(?:tariff)='[\p{Print}]+'/)`

It's important to understand what the pattern is doing. The regular expression engine has some gotchas that can drastically affect the speed of a search, so indiscriminately throwing in things without understanding what they do can be very costly.

When using `(?:...)`, you're creating a non-capturing group. When you only have one item you're matching it's not necessary, nor is it particularly desirable since it's making the engine do more work. The only time I'd do that is when I need to refer back to what the capture was, but since you have only one possible thing it'll match that becomes a moot-point. So, your pattern should be reduced to:

```
/tariff='[\p{Print}]+'/
```

Which, when used, results in:

```
%(tariff='abcdef abc a').scan(/tariff='[\p{Print}]+'/) 
# => ["tariff='abcdef abc a'"]
```

If you want to capture all non-empty occurrences of the string being assigned, it's easier than what you're doing. I'd use something like:

```
%(tariff='abcdef abc a').scan(/tariff='.+'/) 
# => ["tariff='abcdef abc a'"]

%(tariff='abcdef abc a').scan(/tariff='[^']+'/) 
# => ["tariff='abcdef abc a'"]
```

The second is more rigorous, and possible safer as it won't be tricked by an line that has multiple single-quotes:

```
%(tariff='abcdef abc a', 'foo').scan(/tariff='.+'/) 
# => ["tariff='abcdef abc a', 'foo'"]

%(tariff='abcdef abc a', 'foo').scan(/tariff='[^']+'/) 
# => ["tariff='abcdef abc a'"]
```

Why that works is for you to figure out.

Comment: dude what if i get a string instead of integer next to "=" sign??. assume string=<<EOT tariff="abcdef abc a"  EOT                                                       i tried string.scan(/(?:tariff)='[[:alpha:]]+'/), but i'm not getting anything.

Comment: Got it dude. This one worked, string.scan(/(?:tariff)='[\p{Print}]+'/) .

Comment: @hari, Just as a note for writing style, it's better to not say "dude", except occasionally in humor. Comments are visible to the world, including potential employers; something to think about when tossing out comments and presenting yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to parse strings and extract parts of it :

```
my_text = "blablabla" #just imagine that this is your text
regex_mrp = /mrp='(.+?)';/ #extracts whatever is between single quotes after mrp
regex_talktime = /talktime='(.+?)';/ #extracts whatever is between single quotes after talktime

mrp = my_text.match(regex_mrp)[1].to_i #gets the match, and converts to integer
talktime = my_text.match(regex_talktime)[1].to_f #gets the match, and converts to float
```

Here's a quick reference to the regular expressions syntax : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is, the OP has text that has multiple occurrences of the values. Which is the right one? Without that information no answer can be given as we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @theTinMan, dude i want to extract all the occurrences.